How do you count concordant, discordant and tied pairs in Kendall Tau a, b, and c?
Question:

How exactly does one count the number of concordant, discordant, and tied pairs in Kendall's tau?
Does the exact same method apply for tau-a, tau-b, and tau-c?

Note: I am not asking about how we calculate the different versions of Kendall's tau or their respective formulas; this question is only about the process of counting the pairs themselves.
What I think I understand so far (and probably got wrong)
The way I understand it, we have to first sort X and Y by X.
So if we have the following X and Y variables:
X = 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 1
Y = 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2

The sorted variables by X would be:
X = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
Y = 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4

Now to count the number of concordant, discordant and tied pairs, we lay out the data in a matrix that looks like this:
  2 3 3 4 3 
3 .          
3 . .       
4 . . .     
3 . . . .   
4 . . . . . 

We start with the first column (2) and compare each row:
3 > 2, 3 > 2, 4 > 2, 3 > 2, 4 > 2, etc...
By comparing each pair, we can fill the following matrix like this:
  2 3 3 4 3 
3 >          
3 > =       
4 > > >     
3 > = = <   
4 > > > = > 

We now count the numbers of > (concordant pairs), < (discordant pairs) and = (tied pairs)
If the above demonstration wasn't completely off track, we should have 15 pairs: 10 concordant pairs, 1 discordant pair, and 4 tied pairs.
Is the method described above correct? Can this method be used for counting the concordant, discordant, and tied pairs in tau-a, tau-b, and tau-c, or are there some differences?
